# SPARQL: how to delete complete chain of node

Tags: sparql, jena

I want to write a SPARQL query with better performance which can basically delete complete chain of statements for given node. What I mean is apart from deleting statements where node is just subject and object, it should also delete all its dependent chain (Which is not connected to any other existing node).

[image]

For example deleting node n2 above should delete all below statements.

n1 p1 n2

n2 p2 n3

n2 p3 n4

n4 p4 n5

n5 p5 n6

n6 p6 n1

Comment: Why no `n1 p7 n3`? Could you please also colorize properties in triples to be deleted?

Comment: I think this is almost impossible or in the best case, won't scale given that you clearly would need property paths with wildcard pattern `(<p>|!<p>)*`and you want to delete some kind of connected graph. SPARQL is mostly a query language but not the best choice for graph traversal etc.

Comment: @AKSW Thanks for it. Can you please suggest better languages/APIs/Graphstore for graph traversal? Currently I am using combination of TripleSTore (Jena)+SPARQL

Comment: @StanislavKralin: n1 p7 n3 is self standing itself, which doesn't depend on n2, that's why.

Comment: @Pratik, but `n6 p6 n1` is "self-standing" as well...

Comment: @StanislavKralin: Once you delete node n2, there is no way to reach to n6 p6 n1, however there is still way to reach n1 p7 n3, even without it.

Comment: @Pratik what do you mean with "reach"? Reach from where? It's still not clear to me why `n6 p6 n1` would be "unreachable" after deletion, while `n1 p7 n3` wouldn't be.